Challenging Integral Problem
If $I_n=\int_0^a \frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)^n} dx$, show that
(i) $\int_0^a \frac{x^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}} dx=I_n-a^2I_{n+1}$
(ii) $2na^2I_{n+1}=(2n-1)I_n+(2^na^{2n-1})^{-1}$
Here is what I have done, I was able to fully solve part (i) but not part (ii):
(i)
Consider $\int_0^a \frac{x^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}} dx$.
Let $x=atan\theta$, $dx=asec^2\theta d\theta$.
$$a^2+x^2=a^2+a^2tan^2\theta=a^2(1+tan^2\theta)=a^2sec^2\theta$$
Then:
$$\int_0^a \frac{x^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}} dx=\int_0^{arctan\frac{x}{a}} \frac{a^2tan^2\theta}{(a^2sec^2\theta)^{n+1}}asec^2\theta d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^{arctan\frac{x}{a}} \frac{a^3sec^2\theta(sec^2\theta-1)}{(a^2sec^2\theta)^{n+1}}d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^{arctan\frac{x}{a}} \frac{a^3sec^4\theta}{(a^2sec^2\theta)^{n+1}}d\theta-\int_0^{arctan\frac{x}{a}}\frac{a^3sec^2\theta}{(a^2sec^2\theta)^{n+1}}d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^{arctan\frac{x}{a}} \frac{asec^2\theta}{(a^2sec^2\theta)^n}d\theta-\int_0^{arctan\frac{x}{a}}\frac{a^3sec^2\theta}{(a^2sec^2\theta)^{n+1}}d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^a \frac{asec^2\theta}{(a^2+x^2)^n}\frac{dx}{asec^2\theta}-\int_0^a\frac{a^3sec^2\theta}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}\frac{dx}{asec^2\theta}$$
$$=\int_0^a \frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)^n}dx-a^2\int_0^a\frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}dx$$
$$=I_n-a^2I_{n+1}$$
(ii) I am unsure how to even approach this one...
Anybody have any ideas?

Proving (i) is actually very easy and you didn't have to use trigonometry. Just add and subtract $a^2$ in the numerator and then split the integral. For (ii) perhaps integration by parts would be the way to go.

(i)
\begin{align}
&\int_0^a \frac{x^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}} dx\\
=& \int_0^a \frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)^{n}}-\frac{a^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}\ dx =I_n-a^2I_{n+1}
\end{align}
(ii)
Integrate both sides of the equation
$$\bigg[\frac{x}{(a^2+x^2)^n}\bigg]’= \frac{2na^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}- \frac{2n-1}{(a^2+x^2)^{n}}
$$
over $(0,a)$ to obtain
\begin{align}
& 2na^2I_{n+1}=(2n-1)I_n+\frac1{2^na^{2n-1}}\\
\end{align}

Proof of (i)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^a \frac{x^2}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{n+1}} d x=&\int_0^a \frac{\left(a^2+x^2\right)-a^2}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{n+1}} d x \\
= & \int_0^a \frac{1}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^n} d x-a^2 \int_0^a \frac{1}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{n+1}} d x \\
\quad= & I_n-a^2 I_{n+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Proof of (ii)
Differentiation brings us
$$
\left[\frac{x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^n}\right]^{\prime}=\frac{a^2-(2 n-1) x^2}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{n+1}}
$$
Integrating from $x=0$ to $a$ yields
$$
\left[\frac{x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^n}\right]_0^a=a^2 \int_0^a \frac{1}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{n+1}} d x-(2 n-1) \int_0^a \frac{x^2}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{n+1}}dx
$$
Using (i), we have
$$
\begin{gathered}
\frac{1}{2^n a^{2 n-1}}=a^2 I_{n+1}-(2 n-1)\left(I_n-a^2 I_{n+1}\right) \\
2 n a^2 I_{n+1}=(2 n-1) I_n+(2^n  a^{2 n-1})^{-1}
\end{gathered}
$$
